# Double Shielding -- Insulator between shields?

Tags: rf, shield

To minimize RFI and provide maximum shielding on an enclosure, a double shield will be used. I need 120dB of isolation over a certain range of frequencies and will be testing using a reverberation chamber.

Are there any benefits from electrically isolating the second shield from the first or will both designs have the same RF isolation?

Comment: It's actually a bit more involved: as Olin says, you need the connection so that the space between the two hulls doesn't simply form a capacitor. At the same time, it makes little sense to have a second shield if that just acts as antenna for the voltage fluctuation at the point it's connected to the device...

Comment: Why have you only accepted answers for 4 out of the last 60 questions you have raised (as listed on your profile)? There should be more given back by you.

Comment: At 4MHz, the standard-thickness copper foil (35 micron, 1.4 mils), is one-wavelength thick and you get 1 Neper attenuation between the 2 sides of the foil. What frequencies are you considering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make sure that no currents from your device can inadvertently run thru a shield.  That means there can be at most one connection back to the device or the next-inner shield.

For capacitive shielding, you want the shields connected to the ground of the device.

To satisfy both these constraints, connect the inner shield to the ground of your device in exactly one point.  Then connect the outer shield to the inner shield at the same point.  That way the inner shield still has only one connection.

Just two shields might not do what you want.  Shields don't let RF waves thru.  However, they can act as antennas and receive radiation from one side.  This antenna then re-radiates some portion of the received power to both side.  This in practice makes shields not block all radiation.

You might consider absorbing material between the two shields.  There are ferrite tiles and various carbon-impregnated foams for this purpose.  You have to check the frequency range and absorption characteristics of any such material carefully.

It would probably be useful to have a chat with a application engineer from a company that makes RF-absorbing material.